# Canvas JS not populating graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask, amazon-ec2

I have jQuery code that uses the JSON responses from a RESTful web service to plot a graph. I am using Canvas JS for this task. 
Whenever I run the program, i get an empty graph.
Any and all help is appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    var date = $('#nameInput').val();
    var datatmax = [];
    var datatmin = [];

    $.ajax({
      data: {
        v: $('#nameInput').val(),
      },
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/forecast/' + date
    }).done(function(data) {
      if (data) {
        $.each(data, function(d) {
          datatmax.push({
            y: d.TMAX,
            label = d.DATE
          })
          datatmin.push({
            y: d.TMIN,
            label = d.DATE
          })
        })

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
          title: {
            text: "WEATHER FORECAST"
          },
          data: [{
            type: "line",
            markerType: "circle",
            name: "TMAX",
            showInLegend: true,
            dataPoints: datatmax
          }, {
            type: "line",
            name: "TMIN",
            lineDashType: "dash",
            showInLegend: true,
            markerType: "square",
            dataPoints: datatmin
          }]
        });
        chart.render();
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

The JSON array is of the format

```
[{
  'DATE': VAL, 
  'TMAX': VAL, 
  'TMIN': VAL 
}, {
},{ 
},..]
```

Comment: You have a `;` before `.done` which will be causing a syntax error. Check the console.

Comment: Also note that isn't JSON, it's an array of objects

Comment: i fixed the ```.done``` issue. I am receiving values in the above format. Can you tell me as to how to populate the graph with these values?